# Retrieve response time of a web request within a catch

Tags: c#

First of all, thanks for the help you can give me.

Okay, first, excuse my little knowledge, I'm learning, so forgive my ignorance.

I have a method that calls a service, and it is assumed that if any response other than the range of 200 is received, it goes to catch. Well, I need, within that catch, to retrieve from the header (or somewhere) of that response the time it took the service to respond.

I can't use timer or things like that (it was what I first thought of).

The thing is, I don't know how to recover this data from the exception.

Thank you very much!

````
        {
            try
            {
                // Reading the http response
                using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                 
                   ///// Call to endpoint

                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                  //// Here I need to retrieve the time it took for the service to respond (with the error)
            }
            return response;
        } ```
````

Comment: I suggest you to read httpclient async methods, you are trying to resolve a problem that you should not handle.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/27212359/12387766. Also, you can use HttpClient async to handle all possible response.

Comment: I agree, don’t use (Http)WebRequest. This class is deprecated for almost 10 years now and it’s documentation states not to use it anymore, and instead use HttpClient.

Comment: Declare a `StopWatch` and start it before the `try` block, inside the `catch` block stop the stopwatch and print `StopWatch.Elapsed` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: *"I can't use timer or things like that"*, why?

Comment: I will try to answer all of you. This is something I have to do in my new job. I have to use "WebRequest" because it is a legacy code that I have to put a log to in the catch. Not being able to use
timer, it is for the same reason, they are technical indications, I don't know very well because I can't. The watch would be the easiest solution.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an example to what kshkarin mentioned:

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{   
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream answer = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // do something
            watch.Stop(); 
            Console.WriteLine($"Success at {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e) 
{
    // If we got here, it was a timeout exception.
    watch.Stop(); 
    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred at {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} \n {e}"); 
}
```

Comment: Although I cannot use this solution due to technical indications, it is one of the best solutions

Comment: It would be simpler to use the *finally* clause for the `watch.Stop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you must be set timeout in web request and check this with TimeoutException
if you have some scenario you can check this with simple DateTime
set DateTime.Now and get distance time